# Sum multiple fields in 1 table

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I would like to sum my 4 columns in my table.
but I get error `he SUM function requires 1 argument(s)`
itemcost table

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+======+======+======+======+======+
| 0002 | 5    | 5    | 5    | 5    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------+------+------+------+------+


$cost= DB::table('itemcost')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('SUM(col1,col2,col3,col4) as unitprice')
            );
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To sum just column of every single row, use:

```
(col1+col2+col3+col4) as unitprice
```

Or, to sum columns with rows, use:

```
(SUM(col1)+SUM(col2)+SUM(col3)+SUM(col4)) as unitprice
```

---

By the way, here is an [article](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_sum-multiple.php) with examples

Answer (score 0):

You could add columns with + sign,
Try like bellow:

```
      $cost= DB::table('itemcost')  
        ->select(
            DB::raw('SUM(col1+col2+col3+col4) as unitprice')
        );
```